# Why isn't output produced on the second line by the command: NR % 4 == 1, NR % 4 == 3 { printf "%6d %s\n", NR, $0 }

Tags: awk

I was reading through the wikipedia page for awk recently, just trying to get a bit of an overview, and I reached this example:

> NR % 4 == 1, NR % 4 == 3 { printf "%6d  %s\n", NR, $0 }

> The action statement prints each line numbered. The printf function emulates the standard C printf and works similarly to the print command described above. The pattern to match, however, works as follows: NR is the number of records, typically lines of input, AWK has so far read, i.e. the current line number, starting at 1 for the first line of input. % is the modulo operator. NR % 4 == 1 is true for the 1st, 5th, 9th, etc., lines of input. Likewise, NR % 4 == 3 is true for the 3rd, 7th, 11th, etc., lines of input. The range pattern is false until the first part matches, on line 1, and then remains true up to and including when the second part matches, on line 3. It then stays false until the first part matches again on line 5.
> Thus, the program prints lines 1,2,3, skips line 4, and then 5,6,7, and so on. For each line, it prints the line number (on a 6 character-wide field) and then the line contents. For example, when executed on this input:

> Rome
> Florence
> Milan
> Naples
> Turin
> Venice

> The previous program prints:
> 1 Rome
> 2 Florence
> 3 Milan
> 5 Turin
> 6 Venice

I am confused why the second line wouldn't print, as 2%4 is false for both of the two initial statements NR%4==1 and NR%4==3

What is the reason why this is the case?

Comment: Better explained in [GNU Awk User's Guide - 7.1.3 Specifying Record Ranges with Patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html)

Comment: Let's try again, I didn't like the wording of the first comment: `NR%4==1` prints (is true for) `1, 5, 9 ...` and `NR%4==3` (is true for) printf `3, 7, 11, ...` With awk, X,Y is a range pattern. It is true from the time the first pattern matches until the second is triggered. So it will be true for `1, 2, 3` then `NR%4=3` is true at `3` ending the first range. `NR%4==1` is true again at `5` starting the pattern again and so on... Ditch wikipedia, GNU Awk User's Guide is the ticket...

Comment: I would logicall think the same thing as you, but documentation is clear. Perhaps you are thinking `NR %4 ==1  ||  NR %4 == 3  {... `  where  `||` is the OR condition, which prints when line mod 4 matches 1 or 3 ?

Comment: Or [The AWK Programming Language](https://www.amazon.com/o/asin/020107981X) where on pages 32-33 you get the info that a range pattern written `par1, pat2` "matches each line between an occurence of pat1, and the next occurence of pat2 inclusive".